# What can be in two states at once yet one thing in all?

Tags: riddle, word

A simple one-liner:

> What can be in two states at once yet one thing in all?

What is it?

Comment: Why was this question closed? Why is it be considered "off-topic"? Isn't it just a simple riddle?

Comment: @Dopplegamer The question is too broad, the amount of possible answers is too high.

Comment: @Auribouros Ah, okay, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's not the intended answer, but

> Schrödinger's cat is the classical example of something that can be in two states at once.  Alive and dead at the same time.
>
>  The irony is that Schrödinger's cat is actually an example used to illustrates the fact that being in superposed states can happen to literally everything.  Even a sentient cat.
>  But it ended up to be known as the one instance of something that can be in two states at a same time due to some hokus-pokus done by Schrödinger.
>
>  A more correct answer should probably be 'Almost everything, like for instance that cat in a box'.

Comment: This actually _was_ the intended answer, but all the others are valid too (my question was too ambigious)

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly sure this is not the intended answer but:

> A human, I can simply go between two state borders and voila!

Comment: I can also be in a state of shock and disbelief if our answers are considered incorrect :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm also fairly sure it's not the intended answer, as it would require a [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge)-tag, but

> [Potassium has been shown to exist as both a solid and a liquid simultaneously.](https://www.ed.ac.uk/news/2019/elements-can-be-solid-and-liquid-at-same-time)

Answer (score 3):

I'm also sure this is not the intended answer and is pretty similar to Auribouros' answer, but:

> an interstate highway.

Rationale:

> Interstate = existing or carried on between states, and also a highway system in the U.S.  A single interstate highway is in two states but is one highway.